# Numpy matrix doesn't update value

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So I have a dataset with (business) daily data from 2008 to 2011 for 5 variables stored in a pandas DataFrame called `storeddata`. I want to compute a exponentially-weighted moving average covariance matrix for each day. I have an initiation period (let's say from 2008-01-01 to 2009-01-01) for which I compute the covariance matrix, a 5x5 matrix, called `covmat1`.

Now I want to iterate through the `storeddata`-DataFrame and after 2009-01-01 update a dict called `covfinaldict` with a 5x5 matrix for each business day. I have tried with this block of code:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

zeromatrix=np.mat(np.zeros((5,5)))

for row in storeddata.iterrows():
    if row[0]>dt.datetime(2009,01,01):
        mat1=covfinaldict[row[0]-BDay(1)]  
        for x in range(5):
            for y in range(5):
                if x==y:
                    zeromatrix[x,y]=sqrt(0.93*(mat1[x,y]**2)+0.07*(row[1][x+1]**2))
                else:
                    zeromatrix[x,y]=0.93*mat1[x,y]+0.07*row[1][x+1]*row[1][y+1]
        covfinaldict[row[0]]=zeromatrix  
    else:
        covfinaldict[row[0]]=covmat1
```

The formulas are an approximation of an exponentially-weighted moving average, the details of which are irrelevant. The computation does not work in the sense that I get the same 5x5 matrix (although it is different from `covmat1`) for each day after 2009-01-01. Furthermore, if I run `sqrt(0.93*(mat1[x,y]**2)+0.07*(row[1][x+1]**2))` in console I get `0.1613`, if I run `zeromatrix[x,y]` I get `0.158` (x=4, y=4). This makes no sense to me. How can the left hand side of an equation not be equal to the right hand side? Explanations are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy your zeromatrix object:

```
import copy
```

and

```
    covfinaldict[row[0]]=copy.copy(zeromatrix)
```

Otherwise, all covfinaldict rows will point to the same object.

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html);
*Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides generic shallow and deep copy operations (explained below).*

Comment: Nice, worked! You wouldn't happen to have an explanation for why this is a fix or perhaps a link that does?